# How to create the perfect autosize textarea?

Tags: vue.js

I do auto expanding textarea.

The principle is this: I create a hidden div in which I place the input text, then in the updated () method I define the height of the div and apply the value to the textarea.

But there is one problem - there is text twitching, because First, the text crawls up, and then when the field is expanded, it returns to its place. As if the updated () method works late. By the same principle, I made a text field in the ReactJS there was no such effect.

What can do with it?

How it works: https://jsbin.com/zakavehewa/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

```
<template>
  <div class="textarea_wrap">
    <textarea class="text_input textarea" v-model="value" ref="textarea"></textarea>
    <div v-if="autoRow" class="text_input textarea shadow" ref="shadow">{{ value }}!</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      autoRow: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      default: String
    },
    data () {
      return {
        value: this.default,
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.updateHeight()
    },
    updated() {
      this.updateHeight()
    },
    methods: {
      updateHeight() {
        if (this.autoRow && this.$refs.shadow) {
          this.$refs.textarea.style.height = this.$refs.shadow.clientHeight + 5 + 'px'
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .textarea_wrap {
    position: relative;
  }

  .textarea {
    line-height: 1.5;
    min-height: 31px;
    width: 100%;    
    font-family: inherit;    
  }

  .shadow {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    pointer-events: none;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    resize: none;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at this library called [autosize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autosize).

Comment: it is not vor vue

Comment: I know, but you could easily integrate it into your Vue app.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://github.com/wrabit/vue-textarea-autogrow-directive, it caters for rendering in hidden divs plus copying and pasting text.